# Arrangements of 12 students along 2 rows according to the conditions specified

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Two variants of a test paper are distributed among 12 students. Number of ways of seating of the students in 2 rows so that the students sitting side by side do not have identical papers and those sitting in the same column have the same paper is: ___

*Case 1:*

121212
121212

Students with set 1 can be seated in 6! ways. Similarly, students with set 2 can be arranged in 6! ways.

*Case 2:*

212121
212121

Students with set 1 can be seated in 6! ways. Similarly, students with set 2 can be arranged in 6! ways.

Total permutations=$2*6!*6!$

The answer given is $2*12!$. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $12!$ factorial ways of seating the students. Now you only need to determine the exam of the student sitting in the bottom left corner. Once they have an exam, the person behind them must have the same exam and everyone to the right alternates between the exams. There are two possible exams to give this student so this gives $2 \cdot 12!$ possible arrangements.

Comment: Ah...so we have to count the no. of ways to distribute the papers too. I thought they were already distributed.